# How to install Arc Theme on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: gnome, 16.04, themes, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome

I tried installing the Arc Theme on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 using the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

However, the windows look bad, and they look broken:

[image: Arc theme on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04]

Anything I could be missing? Is it made for ubuntu only? Do I need some dependencies?

Comment: It should work for Ubuntu GNOME as stated in https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme#arc-theme. How did you install the theme?

Comment: @edwinksl I ran these through the terminal:

Comment: `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"`

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arc-theme`

Comment: Hmm, I see. Can you post pictures so that we can see what went wrong? Also, can you try installing the theme manually (see https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme#manual-installation for instructions) and see if that works?

Comment: Here is how it gets displayed

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5333234/14413154/c88bd218-ffc5-11e5-8a49-9f5f97a90ab7.png

Comment: @edwinksl ^^^^^

Comment: Please add any information to the body of the question itself so that your question is self-contained and doesn't require people to read through comments to get the full picture.

Comment: @user276752 Can you try installing the theme manually instead and see if that helps?

Comment: @edwinksl I will try.

Comment: @edwinksl Manual Installation fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @user276752 Awesome! Let me write an answer then so that people face a similar problem can find the solution more easily here.

Comment: I know, old question, but removing the repository you added to your `sources.list` is really a must. Upgrading with this repository enabled may let you find yourself in dependencies hell if you upgrade your system!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme#troubleshooting and looking through the issues at the GitHub repo, manual installation of the theme  using the instructions at https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme#manual-installation will fix the theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want light theme then keep `Global Dark Theme` to `OFF`.

I had the similar problem after doing `Global Dark Theme` to `OFF` everything working fine for me.